# Pandas groupby function with dict.update()

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to use the Pandas groupby function with a dict.update() function to each element. An example in a data frame (just for illustration):

```py
        A                                            B
0   icon1   {'ap1': {'item' : 1}, 'ap2': {'item' : 2}}

1   icon1                        {'ap3': {'item' : 3}}
```

What I'm trying to do is set something like

```py
df = df.groupby('A')['B'].apply(', '.join).reset_index()
```

But instead of using `python', '.join`, I need to groupby the 'A' column and update each element in the 'B' column. I've tried using the map function, but I was not able to achieve anything useful.

The outcome should be:

```py
        A                                                                 B
0   icon1   {'ap1': {'item' : 1}, 'ap2': {'item' : 2}, 'ap3': {'item' : 3}}
```

Is that even possible without changing the item type from dict?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using dict comprehension

```
df.groupby('A').B.agg(lambda s: {k:v for a in s for k, v in a.items()}).reset_index()
```

---

```
        A                                                                 B
0   icon1   {'ap1': {'item' : 1}, 'ap2': {'item' : 2}, 'ap3': {'item' : 3}}
```

Comment: Thanks @rafaelc this solved the issue after some treatment in my data. New thing to learn: dict comprehension!

Answer (score 3):

#### `toolz.dicttoolz.merge`

```
from toolz.dicttoolz import merge

df.groupby('A')['B'].agg(merge).reset_index()

       A                                                  B
0  icon1  {'ap1': {'item': 1}, 'ap2': {'item': 2}, 'ap3'...
1  icon2  {'ap1': {'item': 1}, 'ap2': {'item': 2}, 'ap3'...
```

---

#### Setup

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    A=['icon1', 'icon1', 'icon2', 'icon2'],
    B=[{'ap1': {'item': 1}, 'ap2': {'item': 2}}, {'ap3': {'item': 3}}] * 2
))
```

Comment: This function works, but it returns an object. Would it be possible to turn this object into a pd.Series or Data Frame?

Comment: you need to be more descriptive about what you expect.  None the less, I'll update with what I think you're after.

Comment: @GabrielHisatugu Well, for starters, `pd.Series` and `pd.DataFrame` *are objects since everything is an object in Python*. And in any case, this produces a data-frame, so what exactly do you mean?

Comment: Hey! @juanpa.arrivillaga.  OP, I'm not going to guess what you want.  You can see what I've done so far.  If that makes sense or helps you solidify what you want to do, then edit your question with more description and let me know.

Comment: Sorry, I thought the outcome expected was a good example. I wanted the results to be shown in a new DataFrame, as a result of a groupby function would normally work, with the 'A' column with the 'icon1' and the updated dict in the 'B' column.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a helper function:

```
def func(x):
    dct = {}
    for i in x:
        dct.update(i)
    return dct

df.groupby('A')['B'].agg(func).reset_index()
```